# Create video downloadable link in html firefox issue

Tags: video, hyperlink

I have created a downloadable link with `<a>` tag as follows. It works in chrome but in firefox download is not started instead it opens a url in same tab and not asking to download. can somebody help?

```html
<a href="sample-video.wmv" download="sample-video.wmv">Download link</a>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what MIME type your webserver is telling the browser that file is.

Comment: If I add MIME Type will it work?

Comment: If you can change the HTTP header for the wmv file, setting its content-disposition to `attachment` will do the trick. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition for explanation. Otherwise, you are at the mercy of the browser settings.

Comment: @Mr Lister, Yes agree with content-disposition issue.